# Crud pages don't show add, update,delete in Yii framework

Tags: yii, crud

I'm very new to Yii framework ,and I have very huge passion for it, I have successfully installed and gii i created the model , controller and CRUD pages accordingly . and the problem is as i click the "Try it now " nothing appears and it doeskin show any errors.and yes I'm logged in as admin admin!

can any one let me know what's going on ? it would be much appreciated

Comment: Check your folders controller, Model and view . if your crud operation is successful you will get files on these folders

Comment: it is likely apache user does not have write permission to the models,views,and controller folders. Check if it has